# Tomcat Rewrite Outbound Rule

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, tomcat-valve

I am working on a web application that uses [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for url rewriting. We are looking to migrate to jakarta and intend to also move away from the UrlRewriteFilter and use [Tomcat's rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/rewrite.html) instead, as suggested by Paul Tuckey himself in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75208390/when-the-tuckey-urlrewrite-will-support-jakarta-and-alternatives-of-tuckey-urlre).

However, our `urlrewrite.xml` contains [outbound-rules](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/index.html#outbound-rule), and I can't figure out how to implement those using Tomcat's `rewrite.config`. An example of a rule I would like to translate:

```xml
<outbound-rule>
  <name>R:outbound-rule</name>
  <from>/app/**</from>
  <to>/$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

Looking through Tomcat's documentation and searching the web has given me no clear insight on how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.